# Harvesting from THREDDS using GeoNetwork

Tags: metadata, geonetwork, thredds, data-harvest

I have a THREDDS instance: https://wci.earth2observe.eu/thredds/catalog-earth2observe.html and I am looking for a way to get the data in an ISO-19115 standard format. I have tried many solutions and am currently trying to get the information into a GeoNetwork instance that I have.

I have tried using the THREDDS harvester with the following settings:

**Node Name:** E2O

**Frequency:** 0 00 09 ? * MON-FRI

**Group:** Sample Group

**Service URL:** https://vortex1.npm.ac.uk/thredds/catalog-earth2observe.xml

**Create ISO19119 metadata for all services in the catalog:** Tick

**Create metadata for Collection Datasets:** Tick

**Create metadata for Atomic Datasets:** Tick

**thredds-datasetDategory:** Maps & graphics

set to **Public** and '**All**' is ticked

I am using **v3.0.2** of GeoNetwork

Any advice on what I am doing wrong, or what other systems I could put to work would be appreciated,

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This would be better as 2 separate questions - one for THREDDS and one for CKAN.

Comment: I have seperated the two questions, thanks for the tip